# Strange inline styles coming from where?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome, slider

I have a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060670/why-is-my-script-failing-intermittently), which has been causing me [quite some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060876/why-is-this-twitter-api-script-failing) issue today. :-) The script is apparently placing inline styles on the target element, but I can't find where they are defined.

So the script is a slider called EasySlider. It works quite nicely to display featured content in a slide fashion. However, the script is putting an inline height on the targeted element, which is behaving oddly in Chrome. But to be honest, I'm not sure why or where the inline height is being defined from anyway.

So the height of the #slider is defined as 265px in my stylesheet. But in Chrome, the script puts an inline height of 21px, and in Firefox it renders with an inline height of 271px (exactly 21px more than my defined height).

Any tips on this one? Here's the page in question, the elements being the sliders for each Rod posting: http://tuscaroratackle.com/rods/

The markup is generically like this, and the script makes this into an animated slider and generates nav buttons:

```
<div id="slider-1">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="/img/rod.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="/img/rod.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="/img/rod.jpg" /></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just about everything that jQuery and friends do to animate and alter your HTML for effects and widgets and etc. will involve sticking new "style" attributes on page elements.

Comment: @Pointy...right. Yes, my question does sound a little dumb like that. ;-) (Edited)

Comment: whenever you adjust height or width at runtime through jquery it addes those property's as inline css style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in easySlider.js, around line 65.

```
var h = $("li", obj).height();
```

then a few lines later:

```
obj.height(h);
```

looks like easySlider examines the height of the `li` elements at the time it's initialized, then sets the height of itself (the wrapper div) to match.  The problem is that your LI elements contain images which are not yet loaded at the time the easySlider gets initialized.  Consequently, the `li`s are only one *line* (of text) high (in this case, that's 21px).

The easy fix is to add a height to your images (or to the li elements in which those images live).  If you add height to the li elements, you'll have to ensure that they're `position:block`, so that the height takes effect.   -- it would be much easier here to just add a height to the `img` element.

The more complicated (but more generic) solution is to have jquery monitor the loading of the images, and don't initialize the easySlider until the images are done loading.

Another approach would be to remove the line where easySlider sets its own height.  That might fix the problem in your case, since you're always applying easySlider to a block-level element anyway, it might not need a fixed height.

good luck. [again ;-) ]

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I'll just add the height attribute in...in fact I would have, but hadn't even finished getting all the images up. Thanks for the simple explanation.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Once you implement it, come back and let us know whether it works or not.  (someone else might find it useful to know for sure).

Comment: K, put in the width and height, and all is well.

Comment: One additional question about this mug - if you don't mind me just asking in the comments here - why are the sliders not respecting my parameter for `auto: false;` ? Any idea? The .js file is set to `auto: true`, for the slider on the homepage, and I'm passing the opposite parameter on the function at the bottom of this page so they don't start playing on page load. But is seems to be ignoring that parameter.

Comment: You're passing the value as a *string*:  `auto: 'false'`.  You should be passing it as a *boolean*:  `auto: false`.  (see the difference? strings have quotes around them.  the unquoted values `true` and `false` are special non-string values of type boolean).  cheers!

Comment: Hah. See, simple solution. Perfect. Thanks again for taking the time to explain too.